# Multiple securityTest in app with hybrid and web environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-security

I am developing an app which has both Hybrid App and MobileWebApp.

I am currently using mobileSecurityTest but that breaks for MobileWebApp as wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm does not work.

Can someone please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't protect adapter with two security tests. If you want to protect adapter in both mobile and web environment the security test you use must be the lowest common set of realms. Basically you need two security tests - one for mobile env, one for web env. Security test for mobile env should contain same realms that web env security test has plus realms for device authentication (e.g. wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm). Once you have it - protect adapter procedures with web env security test and protect your mobile env with mobile env security test. You can read more about it here -https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en

Comment: Hi Anton, the problem with two security tests is that how will I protect an adapter procedure with two securityTests?

Comment: [Part 1/2] You can't protect adapter with two security tests, that is correct. If you want to protect adapter in both mobile and web environment the security test you use must be the lowest common set of realms. Basically you need two security tests - one for mobile env, one for web env. Security test for mobile env should contain same realms that web env security test has plus realms for device authentication (e.g. wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm).

Comment: [Part 2/2]  Once you have it - protect adapter procedures with web env security test and protect your mobile env with mobile env security test. You can read more about it here - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en

Comment: Thanks @Anton. I think it is a valid answer and you could post it as an answer so that other can find it easily